# Errno28 "No space left on device" during pip install

Tags: raspberry-pi, memory, pip

I am trying to execute `pip install tensorflow` on my Raspberry but I'm getting an Errno 28 "No space left on device". I've read from multiple sources that it means that the folder used by pip install during the unzip is too small, but I don't know how to know if it's because it's really too small (I don't know how to know the size of my RAM but I think it's 512MB) or if it's because the number of allocated bytes is too small.

`df` produces :

[image]

I received the hardware without any documents to refer to, but I will provide you any informations you need using console.

(I tried to change the TMPDIR but it had no effect.)

Comment: It says in your output there that the / is at 100% utilization, so you are out of space on the root partition. Did you tell the pi to expand itself after installing? You either need to go into raspi-config and tell it to expand the filesystem or you need to get a bigger SD card. I expect you did not read the raspberry pi install FAQ, as they go over this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need expand the SD:

> open the PI’s configuration screen (in the terminal window) by typing:
> `sudo raspi-config` run the bottom option just to make sure you have the
> latest version of the configuration software: `update` run the second
> option: `expand_rootfs` click: Finish select ‘`YES`‘ when it asks for a
> reboot

http://cagewebdev.com/raspberry-pi-expanding-the-root-partition-of-the-sd-card/

Comment: I found this page aswell (http://cagewebdev.com/raspberry-pi-expanding-the-root-partition-of-the-sd-card/) but I there is no expand_rootfs so I went in Advanced Options > Expand Filesystem just to be told that "Your partition layout is not currently supported by this tool. you are probably using NOOBS, in which case your root filesystem is already expanded anyways."

Answer (score 1):

"No space left on device" is pretty much self explanatory -- you don't have enough free space on your disk (or SD card if we are speaking about RPi). Even your `df` screenshot shows the `/` (your [root filesystem](https://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/root-fs.html)) is 100 % full. You don't have separate `/home` so you can try freeing some space there or cleaning some temporary/cache files in `/var` (if you are using Debian based distribution something like `apt-get clean` can help a little).

I'm not sure how you created your SD card, but 8 GiB for the entire system isn't much, you might want to get bigger card or use installation method that configures bigger `/` and/or resizes the filesystem to the entire card size if needed.

Comment: I saw a lot of workarounds for the same problem as I mine but no one of these worked. I didn't create anything, I had to figure out myself without informations from my teacher, so I just connected everything so it just starts, I was never told I would need to get back to my teacher for additional SD card, since there is a 16GB one already in the Raspberry (plus I was supposed to do the work with the hardware I was given)